# Why Materialize template redirect from localhost to 127.0.0.1 after login?

Tags: next.js, materialize

I have added a custom login handler for Github:

```js
const handleLoginGithub = (
    params: LoginGithubParams,
    errorCallback?: ErrCallbackType
) => {
    axios
        .get(authConfig.loginGithubEndpoint, { params })
        .then(async (res) => {
            /*window.localStorage.setItem(
                authConfig.storageTokenKeyName,
                res.data.accessToken
            )*/

            const returnUrl = router.query.returnUrl

            setUser({ ...res.data })
            await window.localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(res.data))

            //router.replace('/home')
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            if (errorCallback) errorCallback(err)
        })
}
```

There is no redirect from localhost to 127.0.0.1, but it will happen, do you know why?

This is the HTTP message that gos to our backend:

GENERAL:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api2/gh-auth-complete?code=f87f5157cbf035a73a50
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

RESPONSE HEADER:

```
connection: close
content-length: 681
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Sun, 09 Oct 2022 22:18:31 GMT
set-cookie: vapor-session=ReDSKZniIFtUqq0kThCkLbBe7vBoCpzpCUWqooA6xYQ=; Max-Age=31536000; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=Lax
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

REQUEST HEADER:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:3000
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

The reason why I am asking is, that in dev environment cookie will not be stored if it happens.

Comment: localhost and 127.0.0.1 are the same thing. localhost resolves to that IP address - it's the internal loopback address. It's the same place, just like *123 Main Street* and *take a left off 2nd Avenue onto Main; I'm the fifth house on the left* end up at the same place.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out, I accidentally filled 127.0.0.1 in Github for Authorization Callback URL, instead of localhost. To get browser save cookie, browser should have domain, not IP.